# I'm getting a null value while inserting a new item on a list by using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, null, event-listener

I have created a simple todo application using HTML, CSS, and Javascript. This app will list the todo items. Here we can add new items to the todo app or remove the item from the list. I have created a function to add new todo items to the application by using appendchild() function. I'm getting a null value added to my list while I'm listing the new TODOs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Todo application</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="controls" >
                <h1>My TODO List</h1>
                <p class="addtodo">Add new TODO items</p>
                <input type="text" id="input">
                <button type="button" id="add">Add TODO</button>
                <button type="button" id="remove">Remove TODO</button>
            </div>
            <ul id="list">
                <li class="mycheck"><input type="checkbox" id="check"><label>Attend Interviews</label></li>
                <li class="mycheck"><input type="checkbox" id="check"><label>Visit Consultancy</label></li>
                <li class="mycheck"><input type="checkbox" id="check" checked><label>Learn Aptitude</label></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I need to add a new todo to the application. And the todo application must list the new item exactly how I need. Eg: Go to the gym [In my code I'm getting null rather than "Go to the gym"].

```
var ul = document.getElementById('list');
var li;

var addButton = document.getElementById('add');
addButton.addEventListener('click', addItem);

var removeButton = document.getElementById('remove');
removeButton.addEventListener('click',removeItem)


//Function to add new TODO items

function addItem(){
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    var item = input.nodeValue;
    ul = document.getElementById('list');
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(item);

    if (item === ''){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        //create a "li" element
        li = document.createElement('li');

        //Create a checkbox
        var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
        checkbox.setAttribute('id','check');

        var label = document.createElement('label');
        label.setAttribute('for','item')

        //adding elements to the webpage

        ul.appendChild(label);
        li.appendChild(checkbox);
        label.appendChild(textnode);
        li.appendChild(label);
        ul.insertBefore(li, ul.childNodes[0]);

        setTimeout(() => {
            li.className = 'visual';
        }, 3);

        input.value = '';
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var item = input.nodeValue;` it should be `var item = input.value;`

```js
var ul = document.getElementById('list');
var li;

var addButton = document.getElementById('add');
addButton.addEventListener('click', addItem);

var removeButton = document.getElementById('remove');
// removeButton.addEventListener('click',removeItem)


//Function to add new TODO items

function addItem() {
  var input = document.getElementById('input');
  var item = input.value;
  ul = document.getElementById('list');
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(item);

  if (item === '') {
    return false;
  } else {
    //create a "li" element
    li = document.createElement('li');

    //Create a checkbox
    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
    checkbox.setAttribute('id', 'check');

    var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.setAttribute('for', 'item')

    //adding elements to the webpage

    ul.appendChild(label);
    li.appendChild(checkbox);
    label.appendChild(textnode);
    li.appendChild(label);
    ul.insertBefore(li, ul.childNodes[0]);

    setTimeout(() => {
      li.className = 'visual';
    }, 3);

    input.value = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="controls">
    <h1>My TODO List</h1>
    <p class="addtodo">Add new TODO items</p>
    <input type="text" id="input">
    <button type="button" id="add">Add TODO</button>
    <button type="button" id="remove">Remove TODO</button>
  </div>
  <ul id="list">
    <li class="mycheck"><input type="checkbox" id="check"><label>Attend Interviews</label></li>
    <li class="mycheck"><input type="checkbox" id="check"><label>Visit Consultancy</label></li>
    <li class="mycheck"><input type="checkbox" id="check" checked><label>Learn Aptitude</label></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```